# How to make characters to be written from right to left in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need to display  -xxx.x °C
The °C symbol is placed there by absolute positioning and it will stay there.
So i need the text in front of the symbol displayed like this:

```
-123.5 °C
 -12.4 °C
   7.6 °C
```

Also i want the text displayed on top of a fixed length text section with
a yellow background color like this:

```
 _______
|__-12.9| °C
 _______
|____0.9| °C

<span  id="tempresult" style="position:relative; bottom: 3px; right:14px;     background-color:#CCFF66; border: 3px solid #8AC007; border-style:double  solid solid double;">----.-</span>
```

°C

Comment: What have  you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `:after` will solve the problem of keeping the °C unit identifier at the end of each temperature. To create the yellow box, just use a `span` element set to `display:inline-block` and add a fixed width, like so:

([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qc7saw62/3/))

### HTML

```
<div><span>-129.4</span></div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    width:120px;
}
div:after {
    content:" °C"
}
span {
    text-align:right;
    width:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**Note:** Edit the CSS to use classes for each element instead of tag names.